# How to search values in two columns against a range in two columns to return value if both match

Tags: google-sheets

I have five columns in google sheets which I need to compare two against two and return the value of the remaining column. My first column contains names of people. In the second column, I have the country. The 3rd column contains the ID of the person, the 4th contains the names (to compare against the first column) and the last column a phrase containing the countries the individual has visited (to compare against the second column of country).

Please check out the link to my excel here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c-B9NC1r-zWcVnK1F3X-Y6TDDluFb5bvVCFNiPlZ_bo/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to compare if the name in A is equal to the name in D AND the country in B is equal to the country in E, then return the ID from C?

Comment: Yes you got it, but take not that in B, we have a string of the countries so we'll need to like find if for example, `Country> England` is in `Country>Portugal 2020|Country>England` which is true in this case.

Comment: Still a bit confused, what is your expected outcome, it's not exactly clear from the question?

Comment: I need the ID alone but after those conditions are met. Both conditions must be true to get the right ID - That D contains the value in A and text in B is contained in E.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that someone (or yourself) actually posted a solution inside the sheets. For the sake of documentation I would go ahead and post it here as an answer.

```
={"Some Title"; Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A14), MMULT((A2:A14=TRANSPOSE(D2:D14))*(ISNUMBER(FIND(B2:B14, transpose(E2:E14)))),N(C2:C14)),))}
```

This is giving the same output that you have inserted as `Expected Output`

[image: Final result]